# How to remove old jobs from SQL Agent that represent unused SSRS subscriptions?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How do I remove old jobs under the SQL Agent that represent SSRS subscriptions that are no longer used?

EDIT: None of the answers in the Q below show you a quick way to delete subscriptions from the ReportServer database. 
[How to delete old subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323898/how-to-delete-old-subscriptions)

I think Nick.McDermaid should post his comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I typed 'remove orphan SSRS subscriptions into google and got this: http://www.trycatchfinally.net/2015/01/removing-expiredunused-ssrs-subscriptions/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete old subscriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323898/how-to-delete-old-subscriptions)

Comment: I did some googling but apparently I should have used the word "orphan" and did not. Your first comment gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: Yeah its a trick finding the correct terms

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the tSQL generated by this select:

```
USE msdb
GO

SELECT
     CMD = CONCAT('EXEC sp_delete_job @job_id = ''',job_id,'''')
    ,*
FROM dbo.sysjobs
WHERE description = 'This job is owned by a report server process. Modifying this job could result in database incompatibilities. Use Report Manager or Management Studio to update this job.'
```